# What is the difference between TDNN and CNN?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, cnn

I read about time delay neural network (TDNN) and I am not sure I understood it. From what I read it seems that tdnn works just like  one dimensional convolutional neural network (CNN).

What are the differences between the architectures, if they exist?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer - **there is no difference**.

According to the paper "Semi-Orthogonal Low-Rank Matrix Factorization for Deep Neural Networks": "**Time Delay Neural Networks (TDNNs), also known as one dimensional
Convolutional Neural Networks** (1-d CNNs)..."

Answer (score 1):

They are the same, as far as i can see. The name convolution usually applies to spatial not time dimensions, but that is only convention. Wikipedia also [links](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_delay_neural_network#Image_recognition) the two.

Comment: In signal processing (e.g. audio or radio) convolution typically implies time dimension.